# Getting null pointer with recycler adapter

Tags: nullpointerexception, fragment, android-recyclerview

my app is crashing due to a null pointer with the recyclerview adapter in the fragment code. I'm using this adapter to generate a card view list but cannot find out what exactly is causing this null pointer. The log has it happening when setting the adapter r.setAdapter(rA) in the faucet class.

Fragment code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.faucetcards, container, false);
    r = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.feedRecyclerView);

    rA = new RecyclerAdapter(generateCards());
    lm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    r.setAdapter(rA);
    r.setLayoutManager(lm);

    return v;
}
```

**Update:**

My error is with r or setting the adapter. That's where the null pointer occurs even though rA is not null

Comment: Can you also post the `FaucetHolder` class. Where is it?

Comment: I think there is some problem in these two lines of code `this.faucets = faucetsI;
    this.faucets.addAll(faucets);` where you are trying to copy over the faucets list. At what point in your code are you getting the exception did you try debugging?

Comment: The log has it happening when setting the adapter r.setAdapter(rA) in the faucet class

Comment: can you post your Faucet class please?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  The stack trace should give you a good starting point.

Comment: Posted faucet... I did run debug and it said null pointer exception at r.set adapter(rA)

Comment: Could you please post the full stack trace from the crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Nullpointer at r.set adapter(rA) occurs because r is null.

The reason for r being null is that you tried to find the RecyclerView in the Fragment's parent Activity. But the RecyclerView is contained in the Fragment's layout, which you inflated in the onCreateView method and stored in v. So what you should do instead is:

```
r = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.feedRecyclerView);
```